# Informational comment deleted

Tags: discussion

I provided a comment to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18603279/3927116)

The original poster of that answer updated the question and even gave credits to my comment, but it got deleted somehow?

Why was that comment deleted? I only added some information about new possibilites with php 7 ?

Comment: Sounds like the author of the post took your comment into account when they edited the post. This makes your comment obsolete. Obsolete comments are deleted.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But just one additional question: Would the comment have been also deleted if the OP didn't take credits to the comment's author?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild nobody can say. comments are very volatile things, and often not very permanent. This is their intended purpose. Keep in mind that your comment beeing deleted for obsolescence doesn't count against you in any metric or statistic.

Comment: well at least there is a badge for well received comments ;)  And btw... I have no problem with deletion of my comment. but a short information would be great. Like: "your comment was deleted as it has been merged into the answer" Otherwise everybody should think twice about wasting time to research and write additional comments that not neccessarily require an own answer

Comment: @shock_gone_wild In my experience, the presence or absence of credits in the updated post does not generally make a difference when it comes to the deletion of an obsolete comment. If a comment requires significant research it should probably be an answer of its own.

Comment: @Louis , well in my oppinion this ( I am sorry for the word ) sucks. I'm interested in some kinds of questions and if I feel there's a need to provide additional input to already (very) good answers. I don't want to bloat the site with even more answers.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild you can edit other people's answers to improve them.